# Experience Manager not working for Smart Target

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, smarttarget

I am fetching my promotions through API and rendering on DD4T page. In Experience manager my promotion is not showing as editable when it is taking some time to get the promotion markup. It is not showing editable fields in case of slow response in XPM. When I refresh few times, It starts working. Please suggest if someone have already faced this type of issue..

Comment: Are you seeing both the component presentation and each field wrapped with spans (if you haven't reconfigured) and the XPM markup? In both cases are you still seeing the same XPM markup in the component presentation, or is there potentially a caching issue if you just enabled XPM where the XPM markup isn't being rendered? I'd be interested to see why it's intermittently working if the comments are present in all scenarios.

Comment: Hi Josh, I have verified that in both the cases markup is same, Also wants to mention that if response of my promotion is fast then it is working fine. While debugging the issue I have seen that if a bootstrap js file used by tridion for XPM functionality is loading before rendering of my promotion, XPM stopped  working. Actually, I am rendering my page with fall back(default) component and using javascript call getting the promotions markup and then replacing the fallback component markup with promotion markup. Please suggest, if I am doing anything wrong..